# 301 redirect after changing word in url

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

the actual url structure is:

> domain.com/browse-string.html

examples of old url:
domain.com/browse-nature-videos-1-date.html
domain.com/browse-science-videos-1-views.html

I have changed the world browse so the new url is

> domain.com/newword-string.html

How can I 301 redirect old to new?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple `RewriteRule` and check for the start of the string to be "browse".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^browse(.*)$ /newword$1 [L,R=301]
```

<sup>**Make sure you change `newword` to the new word you want.**</sup>

You can test it here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

[image]
<sup>*Sorry for handwriting abilities*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Place the following in the .htaccess file and it should work:

```
Redirect 301 /oldfile.html /newfile.html
```

Edit: Since you need rule/pattern based redirection, the following thread should fix you up:

[HTACCESS redirection with a word replacement in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629908/htaccess-redirection-with-a-word-replacement-in-url)

Comment: that will not do it the string is not static thats why i left a few url examples

Comment: Please check the Edit on my answer above.