# URL Redirection with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

Is that possible with .htaccess to redirect like this

```
example.com/page1-sometext-book to example.com/page1-sometext-booking
example.com/page2-onlytext-book to example.com/page2-onlytext-booking
...
example.com/textN-book to example.com/textN-booking
```

Thank you.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/?page(\d+)-book$ /page$1-booking [R,L]`

Comment: page string is not fixed to be page

Comment: I did this but not working RewriteRule ^/?(\d+)-book /$1-booking [R,L]

Comment: I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629908/htaccess-redirection-with-a-word-replacement-in-url) but its not helpful.